# How come I'm getting authenticate error, but when I login via the app, I am able to log in

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, jdbc, database-connectivity

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to
> authenticate the user fakeaccount@gmail.com  in Active Directory
> (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerADAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerADAL4JUtils.java:62)
> ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]   at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:4442)
> ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]   at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4415)
> ~[mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar:na]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. With that knowledge please ask a proper question (at least improve this one).

Comment: You may want to go through this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by [Jatin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894565/jatin). You could refer to Azure Active Directory authentication [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connect-using-activedirectorymsi-authentication-mode), where you could find different authentication methods and below is the sample example of connecting Azure Active Directory with MSI authentication method.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource;

public class AAD_MSI {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setServerName("aad-managed-demo.database.windows.net"); // Replace with your server name
        ds.setDatabaseName("demo"); // Replace with your database name
        ds.setAuthentication("ActiveDirectoryMSI");
        // Optional
        ds.setMSIClientId("94de34e9-8e8c-470a-96df-08110924b814"); // Replace with Client ID of User-Assigned Managed Identity to be used

        try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SUSER_SNAME()")) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("You have successfully logged on as: " + rs.getString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```